# How to get all documents in a collection in firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to get all documents in my collection but the log return an empty array and i am having an error message that says cannot read property of undefined reading forEach. i have followed the documentation but can't find where the issue is. Can someone help, please?
The code snippet below is a custom hook i am using it in my index.js as per following. this log return an empty array.

```
const { docs } = useFireStore('barbers')
    console.log('docs',docs)
```

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { collection, getDocs, querySnapshot } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import {db} from '../../../base'
export const  useFireStore = (mycollection) => {
   
    const [docs, setdocs] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
    
    const  unsub = async () => {

        await getDocs(collection(db,mycollection))
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let document =[];
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            document.push({...doc.data() ,id: doc.id});
            //console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
          });
          setdocs(document);
    } 

    
      return () => unsub();
       
      
    }, [mycollection])
    
    return { docs };
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drew's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71214845/209103) gets you the documents once, so .

If you want to listen for updates to the documents however, and show those in your UI, use `onSnapshot` instead of `getDocs`:

```
export const useFireStore = (mycollection) => {
  const [docs, setdocs] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsub = onSnapshot(collection(db, mycollection), (querySnapshot) => {
      const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        return {
          ...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id
        }
      });
      setdocs(documents);
    });
    return () => unsub();
  }, [mycollection])
}
```

This:

- Uses `onSnapshot` instead of `getDocs` so that you also listen for updates to the data.
- No longer returns the `docs` state variable, as that seems error prone.
- Now correctly returns a function that unsubscribes the `onSnapshot` listener.

Answer (score 4):

The query snapshot, if I'm not mistaken, is the return value you waited for when you called `getDocs`. You are also redeclaring the `document` array each time in the `forEach` callback, it should declared *outside* the loop, along with the `setDocs` state updater function.

```
export const  useFireStore = (mycollection) => {
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {\
    const  unsubscribe = async () => {
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db,mycollection));

      const document =[];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        document.push({
          ...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id
        });
      });
      setdocs(document);
    }
    
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [mycollection]);
    
  return { docs };
}
```