# How to get all documents on a nested firebase collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a nested subcollection that looks like:

```
users > user.id > cart > doc.id
```

And I am trying to get ALL documents on that collection. Here's how I get a single one:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getStyleProfile = async (user: any) => {
  if (user) {
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", `${user.uid}`, 'cart', `${1}`);
    onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
      setStyleProfile(doc.data())
    });
  }
  }
  getStyleProfile(user)

}, [user?.uid])
```

Which returns the first document:

```
{price: 400, property_id: 1} 'style values'
```

My question is: how can I return all the documents, no matter the ID?

Any question I've seen doesn't relate to subcollections, so not sure how to get it working, e.g [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71214563/how-to-get-all-documents-in-a-collection-in-firestore)

Comment: your docRef is referring to a document, you should refer it as collection without passing the `${1}` . you can find more here: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-get-sub-collections#firestore_data_get_sub_collections-nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#references), you build a reference to a collection like this:

```
const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users');
```

You build a reference to a subcollection in much the same way:

```
const userCartsCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users', uid, 'carts);
```

The collection reference is queried exactly the same way no matter how deeply nested it is, as illustrated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection).

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(userCartsCollectionRef);
```